# How to read Content-Disposition header info in camel from Multipart/formdata in camel Restlet

Tags: rest, file-upload, apache-camel, multipartform-data, restlet

I have an endpoint in camel which accepts multipart/formdata on Camel REST usiing Restlet component.

when I accepts the request, i got file with

```
        ----------------------------756387848644087010707938
        Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""; filename="Git.txt"
        Content-Type: text/plain






        git init

        git add .

        git commit -m "intial commit"

        git  remote add origin https://git-com.com/v1/repos/??

        git remote -v

        git push origin master

        # git remote rm origin



        --------------------
        -- Plain clone ----|
        --------------------

        git clone --recursive -j8 https://url/v1/repos/pt

        git submodule foreach --recursive git checkout feature_rockiung

        git clone -b feature_rockiung  --single-branch <url> submodule update --init --recursive
        ----------------------------756387848644087010707938--
```

I am stuck with

1. read Body only
2. read "**filename**" to store locally with same name.

Any example for Camel -Restlet - REST Consumer  - File Upload .